# how to add swiping in bottom fragment code

Tags: android, kotlin

I have bottom navigation code its working fine but the swapping not working how to add swapping code ?

I used fragment and bottom navigation in kotlin

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener=BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_shop -> {
                // toolbar!!.title="live Track"
                fragment=StoreFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.navigation_gifts -> {
                //toolbar!!.title="Team Management"
                fragment=GiftsFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.navigation_cart -> {
                //toolbar!!.title="All task"
                fragment=CartFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                // toolbar!!.title="Report"
                fragment=ProfileFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }

        true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom navigation bar does not suppose to provide swiping for your  Fragments. If you want to swipe, then you must use view-pager with your navigation bar.

Take a look 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager